# C++ Testing of a given class

Tags: c++, testing, linker

This is regarding creating test stub function. Given following code.

```
//header///
class A {
public:
void run();
};

//cpp///
void getValue() {
}

A::run() {
}
```

if the test uses the already built A.o file, is there a way to give a new definition to getValue() in tests?

Also,

```
//header//
class B {
void get();
}

//cpp//

B::get() {
}
```

If linking agains B.o, what are the ways to give a different definition to ::get()?

Comment: I think you are actually looking for dependency injection and mocking.

Comment: To make unit testable code you should derive ALL your classes from abstract baseclasses. No class should create other classes directly but you should inject interfaces (abstract base classes) to those other classes (that is the dependency injection part). You can then test a class in isolation by injecting implementations of the interface that mock certain behavior (the mocking part). This also requires you to put your class implementations in static C++ libraries which you then can link with either the real executable or a test executable.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://google.github.io/googletest/ specially : https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html

Comment: thanks for the input. I can not change those classes as they are coming from a separate part of the project and I would like to have a stub/mock to those functions which are called from my classes that shall be tested.

Comment: Offtopic: `getValue()` whic returns `void` is confusing name of function.

Comment: If you have a class which is external and you like to mock it, you need a way to replace it. The easiest way is to hide external class behind some abstraction which then you could mock. You can do this by dynamic-polymorphism (virtual methods) or static-polymorphism (templates).

Comment: "... those functions which are called from my classes that shall be tested."  Its your classes you want to test, so you can write them in a way that they are testable. Your classes need the dependency injected not the others you are using

Comment: I agree with others regarding dependency injection. Have the classes hold a `std::function<T()>` that can optionally be passed to the c’tor, falling back to the hidden (anonymous NS?) function. Then in the test, pass in a function to do what you want.